# Looking for a book set on a generationship

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

The book I'm looking for is not Ender's Game or Ready Player One.

This book is based on a generationship that has been travelling for several years. At least 2 generations were born on the ship. The nature of the ship fosters cooperation rather than competition to the point where even in gym class the students are reprimanded for finishing first.

Classes are taught in VR pods with teacher commentary. One student, instead of getting the lesson finds himself in a VR role playing game. He meets with other young adults his age and they are given a quest.

I read this book between 10 and 15 years ago, but while I remember the plot, the title and the author escapes me. I would really appreciate your help in identifying the book. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! I hope one our story-id experts can find what you are looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sounds like it could be  "[The Whims of Creation](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?17709)" by Simon Hawke, in which case this is a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/trying-to-track-ya-novel-virtual-reality-simulation-aboard-an-interstellar-gen).

Specifically matching is [this website](http://www.sfbookcase.com/viewbook.asp?bookno=2419):

> As the baffled, frightened colonists search for answers, a young misfit named Ulysses stumbles upon a clue -- an alternative virtual reality within an interactive cybergame. A place where anything can happen, because the software is alive.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I just spent 6 months searching for this book!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a wild guess here even though it was published earlier.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Beyond_the_Stars

Try googling "novels with generation ships" and see if anything leaps out at you.

Comment: Can you explain why this book might fit?

Comment: It was published prior to the date stated in the original post and is set on a generation ship.  Not much, I know.  (Hence the "wild guess".)  That and the fact that it is a pretty good story and, as such memorable.

Comment: Reading the Wikipedia entry linked, I'd have to say that this is likely not the one the OP read. Generation ship is about the only "connection" I can see.

Comment: Also, in general, telling someone to google a generic phrase makes for a poor answer.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but that's definately not the book I was looking for.

Comment: JohnP I hear you.  But when a book sounds like one I've read I'll put it out there.  As for googling stuff, that's how I generally find answers to my own questions, especially if I'm willing to go a little deep.