# 80's-90's book with an inter-generational ship, society in despair, mythical creatures appear and kidnap kids for a quest

Tags: story-identification, books, magical-creatures, generation-ship

Read this book in the 80’s or 90’s. Sci-fi fantasy set aboard a generational ship, people despair because life has no meaning. Suddenly mythical creatures start appearing and some children are kidnapped into a quest with them. Parents watch via virtual reality and can help kids on the quest by sending clues.

Comment: This is either a YA novel or something by Philip K. Dick.

Comment: Don’t think it was Phil..& I think more adult than YA as there were some sexy scenes in the book involving VR & some hot guys having a threesome with a lady security officer.

Comment: see OP confirmation comment below

Answer (score 5):

[*The Whims of Creation*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/437486.The_Whims_of_Creation) (1995) by Simon Hawkes?

From [SFBookcase](http://www.sfbookcase.com/viewbook.asp?bookno=2419):

> The Third Millennium: The multigenerational space ark, Agamemnon, is a perfect ecosystem, designed to support 100,000 human colonists and their descendants as they journey to a distant star system. But halfway through the voyage, something has gone drastically wrong.
>
> **Depression is rampant. Suicides are on the increase. And in a society where no one has ever heard of fairies, much less dwarves or unicorns or dragons, strange fantastic creatures have started to appear.** How could this happen in the closed, controlled environment of the ark? Are they a threat to the humans? Can the elusive creatures reproduce?
>
> As the baffled, frightened colonists search for answers, a young misfit named Ulysses stumbles upon a clue -- an alternative virtual reality within an interactive cybergame. A place where anything can happen, because the software is alive.

Can't confirm the three being kidnapped, but according to [this Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1HZF4TBYPVCFW/),

> Three teenagers experience a different virtual reality simulation than the rest of their class.

---

Found by browsing this site for `[story-identification] ship quest` which returned, among others, [Looking for a book set on a generationship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/187309) and its duplicate-target [Trying to track YA novel - virtual reality simulation aboard an interstellar generation ship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/51136); the links are taken from the answers to these questions.

Comment: This could be it...it’s awfully close. I’ll check it out thanks 

Comment: Thank you! I just read the sample & I think that’s it! You don’t know how long this has been bugging me! Years! I’ve read his Wizard books, so must have grabbed this one too. THANKS 